# Python binary messes up some files

Tags: python, binary

I have written two python scripts. One of which encodes the file to binary, stores it as a textfile for later decryption. The other script can turn the textfile back into readable information, or at least, that's my aim.

script 1 (encrypt)
(use any .png image file as input, any .txt file as output):

```
u_input = input("What file to encrypt?")
file_store = input("Where do you want to store the binary?")
character = "" #Blank for now
encrypted = "" #Blank for now, stores the bytes before they are written

with open(u_input, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if not c:
            f.close()
            break
        encrypted = encrypted + str(bin(ord(c))[2:].zfill(8))
print("")
print(encrypted) # This line is not necessary, but I have included it to show that the encryption works
print("")
with open(file_store, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(encrypted, 'UTF-8'))
    f.close()
```

As far as I can tell, this works okay for text files (.txt)

I then have a second script (to decrypt the file)
Use the previously created .txt file as source, any .png file as dest:

```
u_input =("Sourcefile:")
file_store = input("Decrypted output:")
character = ""
decoded_string = ""

with open(u_input, 'r' as f:
    while True:
        c = f.read(1)
        if not c:
            f.close()
            break
        character = character + c
        if len(character) % 8 == 0:
            decoded_string = decoded_string + chr(int(character, 2))
            character = ""

with open(file_store, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(decoded_string, 'UTF-8'))
    f.close()
    print("SUCCESS!")
```

Which works partially. i.e. it writes the file. However, I cannot open it or edit it. When I compare my original file (img.png) with my second file (img2.png), I see characters have been replaced or line breaks not entered correctly. I can't view the file in any image viewing / editing program. I do not understand why.

Please could someone try to explain and provide a solution (albeit, partial)? Thanks in advance.

*Note: I am aware that my use of "encryption" and "decryption" are not necessarily used correctly, but this is a personal project, so it doesn't matter to me*

Comment: `"%s"% u_input`? What are you expecting that to do that `u_input` can't do by itself?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, edited my script accordingly

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  It looks like you are rolling your own codec, but you can probably just use base64 instead.

Comment: @SvenMarnach , that achieved the same outcome I am afraid, I also need the output to be in binary as I will be transferring the data through self designed and built means.

Comment: You should also realize that building up a string character-by-character can become slow for large files, it's a n^2 operation.

Comment: I am aware character by character can become slow, as I found out when I tried to convert a PDF file. I will later look into alternatives, but for now this is basic. Thanks though.

Comment: For more on that topic see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/ I think you'll like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're using Python 3, as you put a `UTF-8` parameter on the `bytes` call. That's your problem - the input should be decoded to a byte string, but you're putting together a Unicode string instead, and the conversion isn't 1:1. It's easy to fix.

```
decoded_string = b""
# ...
decoded_string = decoded_string + bytes([int(character, 2)])
# ...
f.write(decoded_string)
```

For a version that works in both Python 2 and Python 3, another small modification. This actually measures faster for me in Python 3.5 so it should be the preferred method.

```
import struct
# ...
decoded_string = decoded_string + struct.pack('B', int(character, 2))
```

Comment: I'll give this a try shortly, and i'll let you know the results.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this has fixed my program and it now works as it should do. Much appreciated.

Comment: Please help, I tried to run the code on a different python installation and now the outputted file contains square brackets with numbers in it rather than the data. What can I do to fix this? thanks.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher that's the difference between Python 3 and Python 2. Use `chr(int(character, 2))` instead of `bytes([int(character, 2)])`. I don't think there's a single construct that works the same in both 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks, that has worked, really don't know why I didn't try that before.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher a little research found a method that *does* work in both 2 and 3.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work. I get an error "error: cannot convert argument to integer". But thank you anyway.

Comment: @HarveyFletcher sorry, my fault. I've fixed it.